# geom_polygon/geom_path with wide data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to be able to draw a polygon from wide data such that I have several variables specifying the first, second... x coordinate and same for the y.

Right now the only solution I know is to use geom_polygon and make my data 4x longer than it needs to be (one row per point). I would like to be able to do this without altering the number of rows in my data.

I've created a dummy example here where I would like to draw and fill the trapezoid specified by the one row data frame created below. I have plotted it with points just to show that it is a trapezoid.

The second "plot" is an attempt to use geom_polygon with wide data. I want to be able to say the x's are these columns from the data frame. In the real thing I will also be grouping as my data is more than one row.

Thank you!

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

DATA <- data.frame(
  x_low_left = c(2),
  x_low_right = c(8),
  x_upper_right = c(10),
  x_upper_left = c(0),
  y_low_left = c(0),
  y_low_right = c(0),
  y_upper_right = c(6),
  y_upper_left = c(6)
)

ggplot(DATA) +
  geom_point(aes(x_low_left, y_low_left)) +
  geom_point(aes(x_low_right, y_low_right)) +
  geom_point(aes(x_upper_right, y_upper_right)) +
  geom_point(aes(x_upper_left, y_upper_left)) +
  coord_fixed(ylim = c(-2, 8), xlim = c(-2, 12))

ggplot(DATA) +
  geom_polygon(x=c(x_low_left, x_low_right, x_upper_right, x_upper_left),
            y=c(y_low_left, y_low_right, y_upper_right, y_upper_left)) +
  coord_fixed(ylim = c(-2, 8), xlim = c(-2, 12))
```

Comment: Sure. All you need to do is create your own versions of those Geoms that work with the data in your format. Lots of examples for how to create Geoms, including in the ggplot2 2.0+ vignettes.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on that a little bit? I haven't done anything like before.

Comment: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html